# How can I use my local ubuntu linux pc as server? And how I can access it remotely from anywhere I like, such as aws or digital ocean instance

Tags: ubuntu, server, cloud, host

I want to use my machine as a remote server like a digital ocean instance.
My machine has 64 GB RAM, 8 TB HDD. Help me to use at least third party software to do this.

Comment: What is the use case? For hosting a website? A web service? Chat bot? Game server?  Or just want to access the server remotely via SSH?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**CONNECTING ON THE SAME NETWORK**

`ssh USERNAME@LOCAL_IP_OF_PC` on a command prompt or terminal

Get local ip from from `ifconfig -a` on the linux server

**CONNECTING ANYWHERE**

To do this you must port forward your router. If you are unsure how to do this, google your provider/ router model and ask google how to port forward it. This can be done in your admin console of your router, and should give you options similar to this:

```
External/WAN Port:
LAN IP:
Internal/LAN Port:
```

And should be configured as follows.

```
External/WAN Port: random number such as 2345, has to be within 
standard port range and not assigned to a default purpose such as port 80
LAN IP: The internal address of your linux sevrer (get this from `ifconfig -a`)
Internal/LAN Port: 22
```

To connect, do `ssh USERNAME@YOUR_PUBLIC_IP -p WAN_PORT`, which will do as follows

**WAN_IP:WAN_PORT** --Redirect-> **LAN_IP:22**

The lan ip and lan port of your server will stay invisible and protected for obvious reasons this way. The wan port acts as a proxy that will redirect the ssh connection to the valid local ip and port 22.